# AVFoundation Mutex interlock on AVAudioPlayerNode.Stop

Tags: swift, xcode, avfoundation, mutex

I am trying to write my first Swift application, and its running great!… in the simulator.  The application is generating tones via AVFoundation, and it works well when I start playing the tones on the iPhone, but as soon as i try to stop the AVAudioPlayerNode, then 5 out of 10 times my iPhone application freezes up. Everything is working perfectly in the simulator.

Here are the stopping code:

```
@IBAction func togglePlay(_ sender: UIButton) {
        if tone.isPlaying {
            engine.mainMixerNode.volume = 0.0
            tone.stop() // This is where is freezes up and tone is a AVAudioPlayerNode 
            engine.reset() // engine is a AVAudioEngine
            sender.setImage(UIImage(named:"icons8-play-100")!, for: UIControl.State())        
        } else {
            tone.preparePlaying()
            tone.play()
            engine.mainMixerNode.volume = 1.0
                        sender.setImage(UIImage(named:"icons8-stop-filled-100")!, for: UIControl.State())
        }
```

If i pause the code when it freeze and look at the stack trace, then it looks like it's waiting for some sort of Mutex be be released. But I'm not experienced enough to know how to investigate further on what i'm doing wrong

Here are the stack trace:

```
VFAudio`-[AVAudioPlayerNode stop]:

    0x187b68c34 <+0>:   stp    x22, x21, [sp, #-0x30]!

    0x187b68c38 <+4>:   stp    x20, x19, [sp, #0x10]

    0x187b68c3c <+8>:   stp    x29, x30, [sp, #0x20]

    0x187b68c40 <+12>:  add    x29, sp, #0x20            ; =0x20 

    0x187b68c44 <+16>:  mov    x21, x0

    0x187b68c48 <+20>:  adrp   x8, 177438

    0x187b68c4c <+24>:  add    x8, x8, #0x700            ; =0x700 

    0x187b68c50 <+28>:  ldr    x19, [x8]

    0x187b68c54 <+32>:  cbz    x19, 0x187b68c70          ; <+60>

    0x187b68c58 <+36>:  ldr    x8, [x19]

    0x187b68c5c <+40>:  ldr    x8, [x8, #0x10]

    0x187b68c60 <+44>:  mov    x0, x19

    0x187b68c64 <+48>:  blr    x8

    0x187b68c68 <+52>:  mov    x20, x0

    0x187b68c6c <+56>:  b      0x187b68c74               ; <+64>

    0x187b68c70 <+60>:  mov    w20, #0x0

    0x187b68c74 <+64>:  adrp   x8, 177435

    0x187b68c78 <+68>:  add    x8, x8, #0x9dc            ; =0x9dc 

    0x187b68c7c <+72>:  ldrsw  x8, [x8]

    0x187b68c80 <+76>:  ldr    x21, [x21, x8]

    0x187b68c84 <+80>:  ldr    x8, [x21]

    0x187b68c88 <+84>:  ldr    x8, [x8, #0x198]

    0x187b68c8c <+88>:  mov    x0, x21

    0x187b68c90 <+92>:  blr    x8

    0x187b68c94 <+96>:  ldr    x0, [x21, #0x8] <— This is where it breaks

libsystem_kernel.dylib`__psynch_mutexwait:
    0x181c15134 <+0>:  mov    x16, #0x12d
    0x181c15138 <+4>:  svc    #0x80
->  0x181c1513c <+8>:  b.lo   0x181c15154               ; <+32>
```

What would be next step in debugging?

Comment: did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Pay attention to threading in your audio engine setup.
Had the same issue when saved audio frames from the injected equalizer unit:

```
    equalizer.installTap(onBus: 0, ... ) { buffer, _ in
        ...
        status = ExtAudioFileWrite(file, numberOfFrames, audioBufferList)
        ...
    }
```

Mutex interlock was fixed by forwarding ExtAudioFileWrite call to the main thread